# Was there DEA headquarters located on top of a strip club?

Tags: united-states

In episode 1 of the Netflix show *Narcos: Mexico* they state that

> The [DEA] headquarters in D.C. sat on top of a f*****g strip club

If this was true it would have been in the 1980s or before.

Did the DEA HQ sit on top of a strip club at some point?

Comment: So what if it did? A quick google search doesn't indicate that they're illegal, at least nowadays, in DC.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I never said anything about this being illegal....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The DEA was originally located at [1405 I ("Eye") Street NW, DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_Enforcement_Administration) until its relocation in 1989. Your source is probably talking about the Golden Eagle.

Notably, the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/1981/10/31/us/briefing-073695.html) reported on it in 1981 to say that the bar added topless dancers:

> As if the Federal Bureau of Investigation didn't have enough to worry about, along comes the problem of the Golden Eagle. Not the bird, the bar.
>
> For years the bar and restaurant at 14th and I Streets has been a haven for agents of the Drug Enforcement Administration, whose offices are in the same building. It was not actually the hamburgers that the agents favored, but the mood of conviviality that seemed to flow each day after work.
>
> Along comes the F.B.I. In recent weeks the Administration has been pursuing plans to place the Drug Enforcement Agency under F.B.I. control, and bureau agents have started moving into the drug agency's building. The F.B.I. officials, concerned about the image of narcotics agents, made it clear that spending lunch hours and nights at the Golden Eagle was hardly the same as, well, watching "Today's FBI," the new weekly television show.
>
> Sadly and reluctantly, numerous agents began passing up the Golden Eagle, and the bar's owner, alarmed at the loss in business, installed, of all people, topless dancers. Abruptly business picked up and, in the darkness, one may even see a drug enforcement agent or two. Waiting for "Today's FBI," of course.

It's also mentioned in the book [Deal](https://books.google.com/books?id=q8DrAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA14):

> This was a great adventure for someone who grew up in a very small town and had never been exposed to a large city. The DEA headquarters building was located at 1405 I Street NW, which also housed the training facilities. It was in DC’s red-light district on a street lined with strip clubs, peep shows, and prostitutes who stood wearing their “work clothes” in doorways or strolled up and down the sidewalks. I can still recall entering the DEA building for the first time and seeing a bar located just off its lobby area. This was the famous Golden Eagle, where DEA personnel congregated and met after work to “tip back a few.” In a hilarious twist of events, the DEA administrator later tried to close it, but the owner got revenge by turning it into a club featuring belly dancing.

The Golden Eagle is also mentioned in [The DEA Museum Lecture Series](https://www.deamuseum.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ChuckCarter-Lecture.pdf), but only by name.